# SCHTASKS /CREATE Weekly on specific time before 10 o'clock

Tags: windows, task, windows-task-scheduler

I need to distribute a task to a couple hundred machines and I cannot easily use an XML file. So I need to work with SCHTASKS via command line. Most of these tasks work well when I use the DAILY scheme, but I am struggeling with WEEKLY.

I have something like this:

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /TN "My Task" /TR "C:\something.exe" 
/SC WEEKLY /ST 7:15 /D SAT,SUN
```

However I always get an error "Ungültiger Startzeitwert" (something like "Starting time value invalid" in English). I have no idea what I am doing wrong. According to the documentation, ST should be valid with /SC WEEKLY. Is this a bug? Any other ideas how I might accomplish this?

Comment: You had to read manual by command `SCHTASKS /CREATE /?`. It says that time format should be `HH:MM`. Thus you have to change `7:15` into `07:15`.

Comment: Thank you, that was super helpful. I read the documentation several times and this never occured to me. Really simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "7:15" by "07:15".

As mentioned on [the official website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-create), the time format is `HH:mm`, by which I think they mean there should be two digits.

Comment: This did the job. I read the "HH:mm" in the manual a bunch of times but never realised it might _require_ two digits.